# Cordova custom URL scheme not work on IOS (unsupported URL)

Tags: swift, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am trying to use deep links to external apps like the following :

```html
<Col>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/channelname/" className="external"><img src="static/youtube.png" width='35px' alt=""/></a>
              </Col>
              <Col>
              <a href="instagram://user?username=username" className="external"><img src="static/instagram.png" width='31px' alt=""/></a>
              </Col>
              <Col>
              <a href="twitter://user?screen_name=username" className="external"><img src="static/twitter.png" width='35px' alt=""/></a>
              </Col>
              <Col>
              <a href="whatsapp://send?phone=+00000000" className="external"><img src="static/whatsapp.png" width='35px' alt=""/></a>
              </Col>
```

it's work fine in android but i have the following error in IOS

***Failed to load webpage with error: unsupported URL***

my config.xml file whitelist

```html
    <allow-intent href="whatsapp:*" />
    <allow-intent href="instagram:*" />
    <allow-intent href="twitter:*" />

    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <allow-intent href="instagram:*" />    
        <allow-intent href="twitter:*" />
    </platform>
```

please any advise ..

Comment: Hi I am facing same issue, did you resolve this issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the following 2 rules to allow opening other apps by URL:

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="whatsapp:*"/>
<allow-intent href="whatsapp:*"/>
```

Access rule plays role of CSP and controls which network requests (images, XHRs, etc) are allowed to be made to specific domains (via cordova native hooks).

Allow Intent controls which URLs the app is allowed to ask the system to open.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) (Custom-URL-scheme)

> This plugin allows you to start your app by calling it with a URL like mycoolapp://path?foo=bar